# Erro ao conectar no SQL Server com ADO

Tags: javascript, sql-server, ado

Estou tentando fazer uma conexão a um banco de dados no Sql Server, so que esta dando este erro

---

JavaScript runtime error.

[Microsoft][ODBC Driver Manager] Nome da fonte de dados não encontrado e nenhum driver padrão especificado

---

Estou a alguns dias quebrando a cabeça para fazer esta conexão onde quero conectar e fazer um select simples so que não estou conseguindo sera que alguém consegue me da uma luz de onde estou errando?

```
function TestConexao(){
  var aCon = ADO.CreateADOConnection();
  aCon.ConnectionString = "DSN=GROUP- 
  NOTEXX\SQL2014;Database=meuBanco;UID=usuario;PWD=senha;";
  aCon.LoginPrompt = false;
  aCon.Open();
  aCon.Execute_("Select * From ConfiguracoesIniciais")
  aCon.Close();
}
```

Comment: `JavaScript`? como está fazendo esse código?

Comment: JavaScript sim to usando uma ferramenta de testes onde estou tentando conectar num banco de dados para testar de forma automatizada a criação de uns campos.

https://support.smartbear.com/testcomplete/docs/testing-with/working-with-external-data-sources/databases/using-ado-and-bde-objects/connecting-to-ms-sql-server-using-ado.html